How do I change the icon of the pkg installation file to a custom icon?
I use Qt to develop software on Mac.
After I use packages to generate a pkg file, the default icon of the pkg file cannot be changed.
Is there any way to change the default icon of this pkg file to a custom icon using shell commands?

I have tried but I did not find a way to modify it directly using shell.

I haven't built on Apple systems for years, so I'm a bit out of the loop on that matter, but I'm not really sure what you mean by "I use packages to generate...": is that a program/library/command actually named "packages"? In any case, please [edit] your question and explain: 1. the steps you follow to create the pkg files (including details about any 3rd party library/program required for that); 2. what you actually tried to solve your problem (eventually including the resources/documentation you followed).

Also note that if the packaging program you're using is not strictly related to Qt, and the problem is exclusively about the icon management of the packaging with no direct relation to the Qt executable or its libraries/resources, then the qt flag is inappropriate other than irrelevant, and should be removed.

Sorry, I'll correct that.

ok，thanks，it's well
